# Why we consider $s$＝1 with BSD conjecture

Tags: complex-analysis, arithmetic-geometry

"Birch and Swinnerton Dyer conjecture" usually refers to an amazing formula that predicts exactly the leading term of the L-function at $s=1$ (a real number $c$ and an integer $k$ such that the leading term is $c(s-1)^k$).

My question is

> Why we consider with $s$＝1?  Is there any necessity to think with $s$
> = 1? Or is it just $s$ = 1 due to the accidental factor that surprising results are achieved when $s$ = 1?

Comment: It is a critical value. Usually (the algebraic parts of) critical values have arithmetic meanings.

Comment: Are you familiar with the $s = 1$ behavior of the Riemann zeta function and its relationship to the prime number theorem? This is modeled after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is any integer **except** 1, then the order of vanishing of $L(E, s)$ at $s = n$ is given by a simple formula (it's 0 if $n > 1$, and 1 if $n < 1$). This follows easily from the functional equation satisfied by $L(E, s)$. So the point $s = 1$, the center of symmetry of the functional equation, is the only integer where the order of vanishing isn't obvious, and thus has the chance to be related to some other interesting and nonobvious things, like the rank.

Incidentally, there's a more general conjecture, the Beilinson--Bloch--Kato conjecture, of which the BSD conjecture is a special case; and this conjecture also has something to say about the $L$-function at $s = n$ for *any* integer $n$. For $n \ne 1$ the order of vanishing is known but there's still lots of really interesting information encoded in the leading term of the $L$-function at $n$ (involving algebraic $K$-theory and Galois cohomology of $E$).

Answer (score 1):

To better understand why $s=1$ is considered, it might help to understand what Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer were seeking. They were interested in the quotient $\frac{N_p}{p}$, where $p$ are the prime numbers and $N_p$ are the number of rational points that exist on the curve $E$ (mod $p$). The original formation of the conjecture stated:

$$
P(X) = \prod_{p \leq X} \frac{N_p}{p} \sim c (\log X)^r,
$$

where $r$ is the rank of the curve and $c$ is a constant. They found the product behaved a lot like the logarithm of $X$ to the power of the rank times some constant.

Then this understanding was expanded upon, and a new formulation of the conjecture was stated: for some function $f_p(s)$,

$$
L(E,1) = \prod_{p} \left(f_p(s)\right)^{-1},
$$

such that $f_p(1) = \frac{p}{N_p}$. The conjecture suggested that everything involved with $f_p(s)$ cancels out at $s=1$ except for $\frac{p}{N_p}$.

And later, the conjecture was formulated deeper in terms of analysis. But the original conjecture is algebraic and considered stronger than the weaker analytic formulation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).